# How to enable sensor simulator in android?

Tags: android, sensors

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Hardware.Preferences.CONTENT_URI); 
startActivity(intent);
```

when i give the above code to enable sensors....they are showing errors....@ Hardware.Preferences.CONTENT_URI);...saying create a class Hardware...plz help...i'm a beginner in android...

Answer (score 8):

You **can't** enable the sensors in the simulator. Straight answer. You can use the sensor simulator tool.

http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Basically, you install the sensor simulator app on the REAL android simulator. Then you add
code to your application to connect to the simulator. Read the installation steps at the bottom of the page for more info.

Comment: thank u sam...but while i'm installing OpenIntent.apk..its not getting loaded into emulator..error message is shown in command prompt
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/OpenIntents.apk 

Failure INSTALL_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

D:\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r3\tool
plz help....
thanks in advance